# Oracle table where two columns define the primary key?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Can I have table like shown in the picture below for Oracle 11g,
where the ID and TYPE columns make up the primary key?

[image: my table]

Comment: Yes.  You can have composite primary keys (i.e. more than one column) as long as the pair of values is unique and neither value is ever `NULL`.  This is true in all databases.

Comment: the answer is Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE YourTableName ADD PRIMARY KEY(ID,TYPE);
```